# How to upload HTMLAudioElement audio file to node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently playing an audio file using an external URL:

```
const url = 'http://s5.qhres.com/static/465f1f953f1e6ff2.mp3';
const audio = new Audio(url);
audio.play();
```

How can I programmatically upload this file to the node server? (so the mp3 file can be stored in the server)

Should I get the audio data and send it to the server using `fetch()`?

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this article online a while ago, it might help: https://medium.com/@richard534/uploading-streaming-audio-using-nodejs-express-mongodb-gridfs-b031a0bcb20f

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can implement an upload function to upload your audioFile

- first we download the file turn it into binary
- second we uploaded

For the backend in nodejs you can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) with express to setup and upload API so you can receive the file this is a [guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088) that can help you

TBN : Read the code comment and you will understand how it works

```js
// load status span
let Status = document.getElementById("status");
// messages for status
const DOWN_START = "File is being downloaded ...";
const DOWN_SUCCESS = "File is downloaded ...";
const DOWN_FAIL = "File failed to download with : ";
const UPLOAD_START = "File is being Uploaded ";
const UPLOAD_SUCCESS = "File is Uploaded";
const UPLOAD_FAILD = "File failed to upload with : ";
// function to update status span
const updateStatusMsg = (msg) => {
  Status.innerHTML = msg;
};
// instansiate XMLHttpRequest
let downloadReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
let fileUrl = null;

// XMLHttpRequest Progress Listeners
downloadReq.addEventListener("progress", () => updateStatusMsg(DOWN_START));
downloadReq.addEventListener("load", () => updateStatusMsg(DOWN_SUCCESS));
downloadReq.addEventListener("error", () => updateStatusMsg(DOWN_FAIL));

// Grab url from input
const getUrl = (self) => {
  fileUrl = self.value;
};

// Download File
const getFile = () => {
  // [TIP] here i added a proxy for the app so you can have a valid cors so it can work locally
  downloadReq.open(
    "GET",
    "https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=" + encodeURIComponent(fileUrl),
    true
  );
  downloadReq.responseType = "blob";
  // Setup listener onLoad
  downloadReq.onload = function () {
    //When the file is downloaded we pass it to the upload function
    uploadFile(downloadReq.response);

    // if you want also to read the file and play it you can use this
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(downloadReq.response);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      console.log(reader);
      console.log("DataURL:", e.target.result);
    };
  };
  // Start Request
  downloadReq.send();
};

// Upload
const uploadFile = (blob) => {
  // Create A file
  let audioFile = new File([blob], "audioFile");

  updateStatusMsg(UPLOAD_START);
  // Sending Using fetch here you can add your node.js End point
  fetch("http://www.example.net", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "Your Content Type",
    },
    body: audioFile,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((success) => updateStatusMsg(UPLOAD_SUCCESS))
    .catch((error) => updateStatusMsg(UPLOAD_FAILD + error.message));
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter the file link" onchange="getUrl(this)" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onClick="getFile()" />
    <br />
    <span id="status"></span>
```